# Why can't I do a "upper()" in my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I created a database in PostgreSQL with "encoding = 'UTF8'", and loaded some UTF8 data in it.  Selecting works fine, but when I try to do a "WHERE UPPER(name) = 'FOO'" in a query, I get an error

```
ERROR:  invalid multibyte character for locale
```

My research seems to indicate that this is because the PostgreSQL installation was "initdb"-ed with `LANG=en_US` rather than `LANG=en_US.UTF8`.  Doing a "`SHOW LC_COLLATE`" shows "`en_US`".  I don't want to have to dump and recreate all my databases, because several of them are PostGIS and it's a royal pain to recreate those.  Is there a work-around, like a way to do the equivalent of "UPPER" that works for UTF8?

**Update**  I ended up doing the dump, reinitdb, and restore of the database, and it was less painful than I thought it would be, except for a bit of a problem figuring out where the data was supposed to go because the postgres user doesn't set the PGDATA environment variable, and neither does any config file or shell script that I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the workaround you want is feasible, but dump and restore of your PostGIS-enabled databases should work fine.  I regularly dump and restore databases with the PostGIS functions and data with geom objects.

What kind of problems do you have?

Comment: The problem I have is that when I do a pg_dumpall, and then restore, it starts complaining about duplicate function definitions and the like.

Comment: just a note for future readers, this was likely due to dumping schema and reloading it overtop of existing schema, when all you really needed was data dump / restore (using pg_dump, not pg_dumpall). In any case, as you noted, really a dump/initdb/restore was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You diagnostic is right, it is a common problem with Unicode in PostgreSQL. The installation procedure tried to be smart and initdbed with the locale of the shell running it :-(

I suggest that, if you cannot dump and restore your database, you have a problem more serious and more urgent that uppercasing the data. IMHO, you should address this problem first, before you have to actually restore your data after a new version of PostgreSQL was issued (or after a hard disk failure).